# SQL UPDATE is not changing

Tags: c#, sql, parameters

The camp @NOME is the Varchar type more its the unique of without not change.

If I pass a string parameter for others without changing @NOME, the SQL other camps change, more if I try change @NOME its not change nothing.

Code:

```
public void Update_Pescador(int param_rgp, string param_nome, string param_end, string param_cel, string param_tel, string param_cid, string param_estado )
    {
        vsql = "UPDATE pescador SET RGP = @RGP, NOME = @NOME, ENDERECO = @ENDERECO, CIDADE = @CIDADE, ESTADO = @ESTADO, TELEFONE = @TELEFONE, CELULAR = @CELULAR WHERE NOME = @NOME";

        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);

                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RGP", param_rgp));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NOME", param_nome));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ENDERECO",param_end));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CIDADE",param_cid));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ESTADO", param_estado));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TELEFONE",param_tel));
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CELULAR",param_cel));
                objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use the same value for the WHERE clause (find the row to change) and for the field value. So you change the Name field with the same value

Comment: What is the key? You can't change the key of a record.

Comment: I could not understand yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is normal because you try to set your `NOME` with `@NOME`

```
SET ... NOOME = @NOME
```

where you have `NOOME` *already* `@NOME`

```
WHERE NOME = @NOME
```

Your update works like something;

```
UPDATE pescador SET ... NOME = 'Somecharacters' ... WHERE NOME = 'Somecharacters'
```

Obviously, you try to update your `NOME` column with itself. That's why you can not see any changing.

Comment: @user3056183 I try to say to do **not**. You clearly try to update your column with it's existing value. Why would anyone need this? You are saying _not worked_. What is not working exactly? You get any exception or error message? What are you try to do exactly? Please be more specific about your problem. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: In the update the NOME column is not being updated parameter. If I do not I change the name value all other fields update. I want change the all values where i pass with parameters.